# Is there a difference between adding integer to a date compare with day interval?

Tags: postgresql, date

I am wondering if there is a difference between

```
select  '1980-01-01'::date + 2345;
```

versus

```
select '1980-01-01'::date + '2345 days'::interval;
```

Besides the fact that the second version returns a timestamp, obviously the question is related to the general case, not this particular example

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference other than the returned type which you mentioned. When you add an `integer` to a `date` Postgres treats it as if you were adding interval type with days. In fact, this operation is explicitly mentioned within the docs listing the `date + integer` operation. Though, it doesn't explain what's going on underneath, one can clearly assume that it's adding the lowest possible granularity (days in a date).

Additionally, note that 24 hours does not equal 1 day which can be observed during daylight saving time changes.

**[Documentation mentions this operation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)**

```
Operator    Example                                  Result
+           date '2001-09-28' + integer '7'          date '2001-10-05'
```

The same operation goes in reverse in case of data types returned: `date - date` returns `int`:

```
db=# select pg_typeof('1980-05-01'::DATE - '1980-02-03'::DATE);
 pg_typeof
-----------
 integer
```

---

The limitation for the first attempt of adding a number to a date is that you cannot successfully add fractions of a day to your date (like `12.5 days`) which is obvious (as it isn't integer anymore), because it wouldn't be able to cast the output to date. This means that `'1980-01-01' + 12.5` returns an error of non-existing operator `date + numeric`.

Comment: So, just to be clear the operation `date + integer` does the right thing about leap years, etc, right?

Comment: Could you specify what the right thing means? If you assume that `'2016-02-28'::date + 1 = '2016-02-29'` and `'2017-02-28'::date + 1 = '2017-03-01'` given that 2016 is a leap year, then that's correct.